# Proper SQL Statements in a PDF?

Tags: mysql

I am in the process of creating an attendance system and have created 3 different reports to generate based on the content of 3 different MySQL tables: `members`, `attendance`, and `absence`.

I am having an issue though. One of the reports is working since I have the correct statement. However, I cannot get the other two to work, so I need some help on how to figure out the best SQL statement for these reports.

The first report I need has to look like this:

[image: Report 1]

This report shows how many people in each precinct showed up to the event and how many excused absences are in that precinct. For this report, I will also need a "Totals" line at the very bottom to count the total number of attendees, excused absences and totals from each precinct (like this):

[image: Totals]

The second report is similar to the report that is already completed. The difference is instead of the member's email and phone address, I need to see if they were marked present and if they had an excused absence. I cannot show the report since there is real data about real people, however I can show you the SQL statement that the completed report is using:

```
SELECT 
  precinct, name, residential_address, member_email, member_phone, present, alternate 
FROM 
  attendance INNER JOIN members ON members.id = attendance.member_id 
WHERE 
  present = 1 
ORDER BY 
  members.precinct
```

I've tried SQL COUNT statements and various JOIN queries to try and make the queries work, but nothing is working at all. What is the correct query and why?

**UPDATE**

Here is my table structure of the 3 tables involved in the report generation. Note that each table (other than Members) shares the Member ID column:

Members Table:

[image: Members]

Attendance Table:

[image: Attendance]

Absence Table:

[image: Absence]

Comment: You're missing some `GROUP BY` functionality. Currently you're selecting everything from attendance and members, but I believe you want to add `GROUP BY precinct` before the `ORDER BY`. Then instead of `SELECT present` you want `SELECT SUM(present) as delegates_present`. For a more specific answer you'll at least need to post your schema structure or table create statements.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones See the update to my OP.

Comment: The columns in these are a little confusing. If a member attends a meeting, I would expect them to have a row in `attendance` but not in `absence` (and vice versa if they were absent). But per the `present` and `absent` columns it looks like every member for every meeting gets a row in both of those tables? Please clarify or correct me.

Comment: Why are you tagging this with "SQL Server" if it's a "MySQL" question?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones No. Each of the reports is made from a form on the application. Attendance marks who shows up. Absence marks who doesn't. The ```member_id``` field is a lookup in each of these forms. So someone will enter the member's last name which selects their Member ID to store in the MySQL table. It's not for every single member, only ones that file an excused absence.

Comment: @JeremyMyrtle so does every row in `attendance` have `present = 1`, and every row in `absence` has `absent = 1`? Some example data here would be immensely helpful in determining the query you'd need. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Correct. Everyone in attendance has the ```present = 1``` clause and everyone in absent will have the ```absent == 1 ``` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested against actual data, but should be close to what you're looking for.

Your first report (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/191d8d/1) should be:

```
SELECT
    m.precinct as 'precinct',
    COUNT(at.member_id) as 'delagates_present',
    COUNT(ab.member_id) as 'delegates_absent',
    COUNT(at.member_id) + COUNT(ab.member_id) as 'total'
FROM
    members m
    LEFT JOIN attendance at ON at.member_id = m.id
    LEFT JOIN absence ab ON ab.member_id = m.id
GROUP BY
    m.precinct
WITH ROLLUP;
```

This selects all members, groups them by precinct, counts how many were present or absent, and then adds those together for the `total` column. Additionally, `WITH ROLLUP` will give you the sums of the columns (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) as the last row.

Then your second report (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/191d8d/2) should be:

```
SELECT
    precinct,
    name,
    residential_address,
    IF(at.member_id IS NULL, 0, 1) as 'present',
    IF(ab.member_id IS NULL, 0, 1) as 'absent',
    alternate
FROM 
    members m
    LEFT JOIN attendance at ON at.member_id = m.id
    LEFT JOIN absence ab ON ab.member_id = m.id
ORDER BY
    m.precinct,
    m.id;
```

which selects all members and does a `LEFT JOIN` on the other 2 tables. Then we can use a condition in the `SELECT` to determine if they were present or absent. There are a number of ways that data could be represented and returned, but I've opted for a simple 1 or 0 in both of those columns.

Comment: On the first report, I get this error: ```Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'at.member_id' in 'field list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ccrp\api\reports\attendance.php:43```

On the second report, I get this error: ```Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'at.member_id' in 'field list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ccrp\api\reports\delegates.php:44```

Not sure what this means?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what schema is unless you are talking about the structure of the database. Yes, ```attendance``` and ```absent``` share a ```member_id``` column. If I'm understanding the error correctly, (which shows that the column doesn't exist), then that doesn't make any sense. How do I look up the schema of my database? Is that the database type?

Comment: Here is the current structure as laid out from before with the code you provided. It does not produce any errors (of course, there are no records since there is no data). http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c93ae2/1/0

Comment: That's odd... How then would I see an error if what you posted is correct??

Comment: I figured it out. Apparently I forgot to add the data into the list that shows the data. It wasn't the query...

Comment: And actually, the second query isn't quite what I'm looking for. It's based on who attended the event. So it's kind of like the first report, just in more detail. This query selects the entire members list. The first query shows all 0's and I have 5 people marked as present?

Comment: Again, you're going to need to show some test data to explain what you're actually looking for. It's impossible to keep going back and forth with minor adjustments without a concrete example. You can replace personal data in your real dataset and load that into a sqlfiddle for clarity (or just set name/address/age/email/phone/etc to NULL or empty string, because this issue isn't actually about the contents of that data, it's about selecting the appropriate relational data across these tables.

Comment: If your second report is just a detailed version of your first report, you likely want to remove the `GROUP BY` and `ROLLUP`, and change the `LEFT JOIN` to just a `JOIN` with the appropriate table. So `SELECT * FROM members m JOIN attendance at ON at.member_id = m.id;` This will only select member data from `members` who were also in `attendance`. Then if you need a detailed version of absent members, just change the table you're joining `members` with.

Comment: Please read over https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and view some top rated questions for examples of how you should ask a question. Screenshots of data are not ideal when something like sqlfiddle exists. Additionally, providing a sample dataset (again, in sqlfiddle showing sample data and then additionally showing what your _expected_ results would be) would be best to allow other SO users to tinker and help you against a real example. This back and forth is not ideal at all.

Comment: Okay..... here is the problem with the first report: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/637ff0/1/0 You can see that the ```delegates_present``` has no data available when the attendance table has records in it. Same thing with ```delegates_absent```.

Comment: A similar problem happens in the second report: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/637ff0/4 Data is not being pulled in from the absence or attendance columns... I've already shown you what the expected output needs to be hence my previous screenshots...

Comment: You're missing valid `member_id`s in both the `absence` and `attendance` table. They're set to the `name` like `CRUTCHFIELD, CHERYL RENEE`. FYI half of writing a _minimal, reproducible example_ is to help you debug as you write the question.

Comment: I replaced ```m.id``` with ```m.name``` in the code and got it to work in sqlfiddle. I copied and pasted into my report code and it still shows the same results as before. No data and shows all precincts in the first report and shows the entire members list with no attendance data in the second report.